# Separation of variables - please help!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I am doing a question on Separation of variables:

[image]

My doubt here is that once the partial derivatives have been found and have been substituted back into the original PDE I am left with a ''+ U'' and I am not sure where to go from here.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you set

$$
U(x,t) = X(x) \cdot T(t)
$$

you'll get:

$$
X(x) \cdot T'(t) + X(x) \cdot T(t) = X''(x) \cdot T(t)
$$

Now, divide by X(x)·T(t) to get:

$$
\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} + 1 = \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}
$$

And each side must be independent of any parameter, so:

$$
\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} + 1 = c
$$

and

$$
\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = c
$$

being c the same constant in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In some of the examples that I have seen the equations will equal + or - k^2, why is it just C in this case?

Comment: You are welcome. c is an arbitrary constant, so you can call it k^2 if you want. Sometimes this is a good idea, because the square root of such a constant should appear in the resolution of the equation for X(x).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the substitution just $U(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$, so you turn $U_t +U =U_{xx}$ into $fg' + fg = f'g$, which can be separated as $g'/g + 1 = f'/f$ ?